# Building with a single x86 platform with TFS Build 2015 (build vNext)

Tags: tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I'm trying to build an universal Windows 10 app using TFS2015 and "build vnext" build system. Code is hosted on Visual Studio Online, build agent is deployed to a virtual machine running Windows 10 and VS2015 in Azure.

I created a simple MSBuild build definition and I specified "x86" as platform:

[image: build definition in tfs]

It looks like the agent is ignoring this parameter and building the .sln with all 3 platforms (x86, x64 and ARM).

In the log, the following command line is executed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\build-agent\_work\1\s\src\App.sln" /nologo /m /nr:false /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\build-agent\_work\1\s\src\App.sln.log" /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\build-agent\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\build-agent\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86 /p:platform="x86" /p:configuration="debug" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"
```

But then I can find the following traces:

- Building solution configuration "Debug|x86"
- Building solution configuration "Debug|x64"
- Building solution configuration "Debug|ARM"

Any idea what could be causing this behavior ?

Comment: Is this generating an appxbundle as an output?

Comment: In the logs I see App_x64_Debug.appx and App_x86_Debug.appx being created. No trace of a .appxbundle file.

Comment: Can you show share your build log? And instead of leaving **\*.sln in the Project field, please specify App.sln.